# Install bootstrap-sass on windows 10

Tags: ruby, sass

I installed rubyinstaller-2.2.3-x64 on windows 10 and i tried to run these commands on cmd:

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
gem install bootstrap-sass
```

but these commands did not work.

Then I tried to install rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p551 and run the commands on cmd:

```
gem install sass
```

worked

```
gem install compass
```

worked

```
gem install bootstrap-sass
```

didn't worked

```
C:\Users\yuzaa\Desktop>gem install bootstrap-sass
```

Fetching: execjs-2.6.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: autoprefixer-rails-6.2.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing bootstrap-sass:
        autoprefixer-rails requires Ruby version >= 2.0.

Please tell me how I can install this?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying to use bootstrap-sass when creating a new Compass project by using this:

```
compass create project-name-goes-here -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
```